# New daily log files created by root instead of laradock user

Tags: docker, ubuntu, permissions, laradock

I have a Laravel app running in a Laradock Docker container, and it creates a new log file every day.

But recently* every day at midnight UTC, I need to go fix the permissions of the log file because it starts having errors:

> `UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/www/myapp/storage/logs/laravel-2019-01-07.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied`

When I run `ls -lah`, I see that the newly created daily log file is owned by "root" instead of "laradock"

So I run `chown laradock:laradock laravel-2019-01-07.log` to fix it. But then the problem happens again the next day.

*I said "recently", and the only change I know about is that I turned off my Digital Ocean server, resized it, turned it on again, and started up the Docker containers.

Whatever I did during that process seemed to prevent new files from being created with the correct ownership.

How can I fix this?

**New info:**

I also just noticed that this command no longer works:

`cd /apps/laradock/ && docker-compose exec workspace bash -c "cd /var/www/myapp/; npm run production"` and causes `bash: npm: command not found`, but then when I enter into the container and run it (as root), it works. So the permissions problem is affecting even more than I thought.

Comment: did you find any solution to it?

Comment: @TheManish I went back and searched my internal issues notes to see whether I solved this. Apparently this happened to me multiple times. Unfortunately I never found the root cause. The only thing I wrote that I did that might have fixed it (although still not understanding or addressing the root cause) was: "This *seems* solved by rebuilding the Laradock Docker workspace container."

Answer (score 0):

This happened again this week. I really don't know what causes the sudden change in permissions.

Again, I ran these commands, and I haven't seen the problem in the couple days since.

```
cd /apps/laradock && docker-compose build --no-cache --force-rm workspace
docker ps
docker-compose up -d workspace
docker ps
```